# Get a list of field values from Python's sqlite3, not tuples representing rows

Tags: python, sqlite

It's annoying how Python's [`sqlite3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) module always returns a list of tuples! When I am querying a single column, I would prefer to get a plain list.

e.g. when I execute

```
SELECT somecol FROM sometable
```

and call

```
cursor.fetchall()
```

it returns

```
[(u'one',), (u'two',), (u'three',)]
```

but I'd rather just get

```
[u'one', u'two', u'three']
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`sqlite3.Connection` has a [`row_factory`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory) attribute.

The documentation states that:

> You can change this attribute to a callable that accepts the cursor and the original row as a tuple and will return the real result row. This way, you can implement more advanced ways of returning results, such as returning an object that can also access columns by name.

To return a list of single values from a `SELECT`, such as an `id`, you can assign a lambda to `row_factory` which returns the first indexed value in each row; e.g:

```py
import sqlite3 as db

conn = db.connect('my.db')
conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
c = conn.cursor()
ids = c.execute('SELECT id FROM users').fetchall()
```

This yields something like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] # etc.
```

You can also set the `row_factory` directly on the cursor object itself. Indeed, if you do not set the `row_factory` on the connection *before* you create the cursor, you *must* set the `row_factory` on the cursor:

```py
c = conn.cursor()
c.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: {'foo': row[0]}
```

You may redefine the `row_factory` at any point during the lifetime of the cursor object, and you can *unset* the row factory with `None` to return default tuple-based results:

```py
c.row_factory = None
c.execute('SELECT id FROM users').fetchall() # [(1,), (2,), (3,)] etc.
```

Comment: Thanks :) I answered this question a long time after the question was first posted (and resolved). As for accepted or not - I'm just glad it helps!

Comment: Thanks for posting. It just helped me few minutes ago!

Comment: Why isn't it the answer? By the way, thanks @DarraghEnright

Comment: FWIW, unfortunately you cannot delete an accepted answer (I tried), but this answer is certainly the right one for modern python.

Comment: @NickBastin Hi Nick. Interesting! I didn't know that. SO seems to have a lot of funny rules :)

Comment: It wasn't the answer because I haven't looked here in years. Now it is!

Comment: Haha :D Hope it helped! Funnily, I just started writing Python again in a new job—I hadn't written Python in the five years after posting this message!

Comment: Please keep in mind that the above will affect ALL of your queries. If you select multiple columns, you'll only get the first one! If what you want is to get a list for each record instead of a tuple (I do), you should instead use:
   conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: list(row)
It would be better to have a method called fetchcol() which would return a list of values instead of sublists or subtuples.

Comment: Wouldn't this limit **ALL** queries for this connection to first column only? Connections are generally reused within some scope, so if it does, it wouldn't be good. Possibly better to do rowfactory on cursor, if possible?

Comment: @Gnudiff — Good question. If you define the `row_factory` on the connection before creating the cursor, the cursor will use that. Otherwise, you can define, or redefine, the `row_factory` on the cursor. To answer your question, if you want to reuse the cursor but unset the row factory, you can do `c.row_factory = None`. This will return tuple results as before. I'll update my answer with this information, might be useful.

Comment: This works on Windows 11. `.\sqlite3 -header -csv py_northwind.db "select * from Categories;" > a.csv`

Answer (score 15):

```
data=cursor.fetchall()
COLUMN = 0
column=[elt[COLUMN] for elt in data]
```

(My previous suggestion, `column=zip(*data)[COLUMN]`, raises an `IndexError` if `data` is an empty tuple. In contrast, the list comprehension above just creates an empty list. Depending on your situation, raising an `IndexError` may be preferable, but I'll leave that to you to decide.)

Comment: Idiom or gimmick? Is it robust? For what values of len(foo) is zip(*foo) guaranteed not to go splat?

Comment: perfect. `columnlist = list(zip(*cursor.fetchall())[COLUMN_INDEX])`

Comment: Jeremiah I think you should pay attention to ~unutbu's warning!

Comment: i think a bit of a race condition occurred here with the typing of our responses. they're all out of order! both ~unutbu's and my answer (below) work well.

Answer (score 9):

You don't really want to do this - anything you do along the lines of using zip or a list comprehension is just eating CPU cycles and sucking memory without adding significant value.  You are far better served just dealing with the tuples.

As for *why* it returns tuples, it's because that is what the [Python DBD API 2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) requires from `fetchall`.

Comment: For modern python please see the next answer.

Answer (score 5):

I use the module ***pandas*** to deal with table-like content:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(), columns=['one','two'])
```

The list of values for column 'one' is simply reffered as:

```
df['one'].values
```

You even can use you own index for the data referencing:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall(), columns=['Time','Serie1','Serie2'],index='Time')
```

Answer (score 2):

`cursor.fetchall()` returns `[(u'one',), (u'two',), (u'three',)]`,

if you want `[u'one', u'two', u'three']`, use the following:

`[x[0] for x in cursor.fetchall()]`

Answer (score 1):

As of some recent version of Python (I am using 3.9.4) it has become even easier to get a dictionary of results from sqlite3. It *is* in the documentation for Python. Essentially just make the connection equal to a sqlite3.Row and off you go.

```
con1 = sqlite3.connect("programs_aux.sqlite")
con1.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
cur1 = con1.cursor()
sql = 'select * from Main where watched is 0 order by Genre, Folder_runtime'
cur1.execute(sql)

rows = cur1.fetchall()   
for row in rows:
    print(row['Title'])

con1.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I started with the following which gave me the same sort of list of tuples:

```
video_ids = []

for row in c.execute('SELECT id FROM videos_metadata'):
        video_ids.append(row)
```

...and so to resolve it and get the list I expected I just explicitly pulled out the first element within the returned tuple...

```
video_ids = []

for row in c.execute('SELECT id FROM videos_metadata'):
        video_ids.append(row[0])
```

This seems to do the trick for me with a single column (per the OP's question) and is quite a simple solution (maybe it's *simplistic* in some way I've not thought of). Not sure how it scales but runs fast enough to deal with the 5000+ entries I have without caring too much (31ms), we're talking SQLite here so presumably this isn't going to be dealing with bazillions of rows.

Answer (score -1):

account for the case where cursor.fetchall() returns an empty list:

```
try:
    columnlist = list(zip(*cursor.fetchall())[COLUMN_INDEX])
except IndexError:
    columnlist = []
```

Answer (score -2):

```
zlist = []

tupls = c.fetchall()

for tup in tupls:

    t = str(tup).replace("('","").replace("',)","")

    zlist.append(t)
```

Now you don't have to deal with tuples, pandas or any of the above that didn't work.

Comment: This is really wrong in many ways