# SQLite and Python: Is there a way I can directly convert output to a list?

Tags: python, list, sqlite

I am using `sqlite.Row` as row factory:

```
db = sdb.connect(database=db.name)
db.row_factory = sdb.Row
dbc = db.cursor()
```

Now I am executing a query which returns a result set with only one column but multiple rows:

```
hodsql = '''
            SELECT perday 
            FROM mytable
            '''
dbc.execute(hodsql)
perdays = dbc.fetchall()
```

What I want to do now is calculate several statistics on the numeric `perdays`, using numpy. I do it like this:

```
perdays_raw = []
for day in perdays:
    perdays_raw.append(day[0])
mean = numpy.mean(perdays_raw)
std = numpy.std(perdays_raw)
```

I.e. I append the first item of each row object to a list, thus converting it to a numpy-readable list. **Question**: Isn't there a more elegant way to directly convert `perdays` to a list (or a dict)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [get a simple list from sqlite in python (not a list of tuples)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854011/get-a-simple-list-from-sqlite-in-python-not-a-list-of-tuples)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really want to convert a list of 1-tuples into a list of items, you do the following:

```
[x[0] for x in perdays]
```

Comment: Well, I have to! Or how can I feed 1-tuples directly to numpy?

Comment: Alright, I figured out that, without using `sqlite.Row`, `perdays` is actually a list of 1-tuples which can be fed directly to numpy, whereas with using `sqlite.Row`, I a SQLite object which numpy cannot handle.