# retrieving data from one table and putting into another PYTHON SQL

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-insert

Trying to take a piece of data from at table in the database and inserting it into another table:

Fetching the order total and assigning it to variable:

```
cursor.execute('''SELECT Price FROM Tracks WHERE TrackID = ?''', (trackChoice,))
ordertotal = str(cursor.fetchall())
```

Putting it into table:

```
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO Orders(OrderID, Date, OrderTotal, CustomerID, TrackID) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''', (orderID, date, 
ordertotal, customerID, trackChoice))
```

Error:

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.
```

Comment: Duplicates with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272908/sqlite-date-storage-and-conversion

Answer (score 0):

With cursor.fetchall() you get all the rows in 'Tracks'. So it will have an ID and probably other informations as well. f.E. something like this: (1, 'William', 'Shakespeare', 'm', None, '1961-10-25'). What is 'ordertotal'? I guess it will be a number? If yes, and you are using sqlite3 you could use row_factory. See the answere here for more information: [Get a list of field values from Python's sqlite3, not tuples representing rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854011/get-a-list-of-field-values-from-pythons-sqlite3-not-tuples-representing-rows)

Answer (score -1):

Why not just do:

```
cursor.execute("""
INSERT INTO Orders(name, Date, name, name, name)
    VALUES(?, strftime('now'), ?, ?, ?)""",
                   (value, value, value, value);
```

That is, use the current time in the database.

(I assume that `name` is really four different columns or you should get another error.)

Comment: I wrote exactly that and got this error: NameError: name 'strftime' is not defined. I added 'time.' in front and got: sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: and yes I just used name to ensure no confusion between the columns and values in question

Comment: @AntsOfTheSky . . . Ignore that.  The function call is supposed to be inside the `VALUES()`.  I just put it into the wrong place.