# How to render Kwargs in For Loop with Flask/Jinja

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to print a simple list of strings that I gathered from a sqlite database. I tested the query result and the list is just fine, but to print it with python (inside a for loop) I would need to do `print(*element)` as printing kwargs.

The problem comes when trying to print it inside a for loop in the Flask template with jinja2. This would print something like `<sqlite3.Row at 0x7fe42f0a5710>` for every element, and I can't seem to find anywhere which is the right way to do it.

This is my code:

```
<select>
   {% for element in my_list %}
      <option value="my_class">{{ element }}</option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```

This is the function that sends the `list_from_db` to the template.

```
def index():
    list_from_db = get_my_list_of_strings()

    return render_template('index.html', my_list=list_from_db )
```

I'll appreciate any help on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this in another SO answer related with Sqlite `.fetchall()`.

Python's sqlite3 module returns a list of tuples even when querying a single column. This can be prevented applaying the [row_factory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23115247/10803457) attribute to the db cursor.

Here is the link to the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23115247/10803457).

Edit: Although this was really useful and it sent me to the right path, I ended up using the attribute [make_dicts](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/sqlite3/#easy-querying).