# Fetching values from another table, with Python, PysimpleGui and Combobox and returning special characters

Tags: python, combobox, pysimplegui

I'm making a control system using Python and PySimpleGui and I'm using a combobox to get the value of a field from another table, in this case, 'product_name'. Along with the product name, I also get the tuple characters ( ( ' , ) ). I need just the value, without the characters. I haven't been able to bring the 'clean' value so far.

**This is my code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('controller.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
    CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    product_name TEXT NOT NULL
    );
    """)

cursor.execute("""
    CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS expenses (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    product_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    quantity NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    total_value NUMERIC NOT NULL
    );
    """)

try:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO products (id, product_name) VALUES (1, 'Lemon'), (2, 'Orange'), (3, 'Apples'), "
                    "(4, 'Bananas'), (5, 'Tangerine'), (6, 'Pear')")
except:
    pass

conn.commit()
conn.close()


conn = sqlite3.connect('controller.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

try:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO expenses (id, product_name, quantity, total_value) VALUES (1, 'Lemon', 20, 41), "
                   "(2, 'Orange', 13, 45), (3, 'Apples', 16, 54), (4, 'Bananas', 12, 32), (5,'Tangerine', 14, 32.5)")
except:
    pass

conn.commit()
conn.close()


def find_product():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('controller.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT product_name FROM products ORDER BY product_name ")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    print(data)
    return data


def create_files():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('controller.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql_create = '''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO expenses (product_name, quantity, total_value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'''
    data_new = (str(values['-PRODUCT_NAME-']), (values['-QUANTITY-']), (values['-TOTAL_VALUE-']))
    cursor.execute(sql_create, data_new)
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    sg.popup(f'Register {values["-PRODUCT_NAME-"]} successfully added')
    window.Refresh()
    dados_lista = list(tabela.get())
    tabela.update(values=dados_lista)


def update():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('controller.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    sql_create = '''INSERT OR REPLACE INTO expenses (product_name, quantity, total_value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'''
    data_new = (str(values['-PRODUCT_NAME-']), (values['-QUANTITY-']), (values['-TOTAL_VALUE-']))
    cursor.execute(sql_create, data_new)
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()

    recordsaffected = cursor.rowcount
    dados_lista[tabela.SelectedRows[0]] = values['-ID-'], values['-PRODUCT_NAME-'], values['-QUANTITY-'], \
                                          values['-TOTAL_VALUE-'],

    tabela.update(values=dados_lista)

    print(recordsaffected, " registros alterados")

    sg.popup('Register ', values['-PRODUCT_NAME-'], ' edited, sucessufuly',
             background_color='green', text_color='yellow')
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

def read_task():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('controller.db')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT id, product_name, quantity, total_value FROM expenses ORDER BY id')

    data = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    return data


dados_lista = read_task()
data_values = dados_lista


data_headings = ['ID', 'PRODUCT NAME', 'QUANTITY', 'TOTAL VALUE']

data_cols_width = [5, 40, 26, 40]
tabela = sg.Table(
    values=dados_lista,
    headings=data_headings,
    col_widths=data_cols_width,
    auto_size_columns=False,
    font='verdana 10',
    text_color='white',
    alternating_row_color='#848887',
    bind_return_key=True,
    enable_events=True,
    justification='left',
    change_submits=True,
    num_rows=32,
    key='-FILESTABLE-')

layout = [
    [sg.Frame('Fruit values', [[(tabela)]])],  # Ok. Funcionando.
    [sg.Text('_' * 270, text_color='blue')],
    [sg.Text('ID....:', font='Verdana 10', text_color='yellow'),
    sg.InputText(' ', size=(4, 5), readonly=True, text_color='brown', background_color='blue',
        do_not_clear=False, key='-ID-'),
    sg.Text('PRODUCT...:', font='Verdana 10'),
    sg.Combo(find_product(),bind_return_key=True, key='-PRODUCT_NAME-'),
    sg.Text('QUANTITY...:', font='verdana 10'),
    sg.InputText(size=(14, 3), key='-QUANTITY-'),
    sg.Text('TOTAL VALUE ...:', font='verdana 10'),
    sg.InputText(size=(14, 3), key='-TOTAL_VALUE-')],
    [sg.Button('Create / Edit', size=(19, 1), button_color=('blue', 'orange'),
        key='-CREATE_EDIT-', font='Verdana 10')],

]

window = sg.Window('--- Fruits ---', layout, default_element_size=(40, 1), grab_anywhere=False, resizable=True, 
    finalize=True)
window.maximize()

# Read  values entered by user
while True:
    event, values = window.read()  # Read  values entered by user

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:  # If  is closed by user terminate While Loop
        break

    if event == '-FILESTABLE-':
        data_selected = [tabela.get()[row] for row in values[event]]
        if data_selected != []:
            window['-ID-'].Update(data_selected[0][0])
            window['-PRODUCT_NAME-'].update(data_selected[0][1])
            window['-QUANTITY-'].update(data_selected[0][2])
            window['-TOTAL_VALUE-'].update(data_selected[0][3])


    if event == '-CREATE_EDIT-':
        if values['-ID-'] == '':
            create_files()
        else:
            update()

    if event == '-SAIR-':
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Get a list of field values from Python's sqlite3, not tuples representing rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854011/get-a-list-of-field-values-from-pythons-sqlite3-not-tuples-representing-rows)

```py
def find_product():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('controller.db')
    conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT product_name FROM products ORDER BY product_name ")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
    print(data)
    return data
```

Comment: Jason, thank you very much for your reply. It was very useful for me and I'm sure it will be useful for many people. Greetings.